# Flask session variables

Tags: python, session, variables, flask, authentication

I'm writing a small web app with flask. I have a problem with session variables when two users (under the same network) try to use app.

This is the code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g, session
from random import randint

def random():
     session['number'] = randint(0,4)
     return None

@app.route('/')
def home():
  if not session.get('logged_in'):
    return render_template('login.html')
  else: 
    return check()

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
      global username
      username = request.form['username']
      session['logged_in'] = True
      session['username'] = username
      return check()

@app.route('/check', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def check():
       random()
       return render_template('file.html', number = session['number'], user = session['username'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = ".."
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0',port = 3134, debug=False)
```

In file.html there is a button type "submit" that call '/check' route. 
The problem is when two users use app at same time because the variable 'number' is equal to variable 'number' of the last user that push the button... there isn't indipendence between two sessions.

I would that the two users has two indipendence sessions, like if they use my app in local host.

Comment: You could put your variable in a dictionary with the username as key and save that in the session

Comment: @MrLeeh
So can i write: 
random = randint(0,4)

session = {"username": "username", "username": "random"} ??

And then how i can get the variable that i want to pass in render_template?

Comment: Create a dictionary containing your number `numbers = {'username1': 4, 'username2': 2}` and pass it to your session `session['numbers'] = numbers`

Comment: I can't write numbers = {'username1': 4, 'username2':2} because i don't know how many users call the function....

Comment: This was just an example. In your code you would do `numbers['usernamex']=randint(0,4)` of course or even `session['numbers']['usernamex'] = randint(0,4)`.

Comment: Ok...so when i will pass the number to render template how i have to write?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using `randint(0,4)` to generate number means that they **will** sometimes be equal for different users. To generate unique number every time use uuid:

```
from uuid import uuid4
def random():
    session['number'] = str(uuid4())
    return None
```

or generator:

```
import itertools
consequent_integers = itertools.count()

def random():
    session['number'] = consequent_integers.next()
    return None
```

Comment: Yes i want that the numbers can be equal for different users. But i don't want that the number of user1 change when user2 do a request of a new number... 
Example: User 1 run app and his number is 3, then user2 run app and his number is 6... when user1 surf in other page of app i don't want that his number became 6 like happen in my app.  Do you understand my problem?

Comment: From my point of you, your problem could be that __any__ action on your web-service leads to generation of new number. As I can see, you should move `random()` from `check()` to `login()`.

Answer (score 3):

So you do something like this. It is not tested but should work. You retrieve the current username and the numbers dictionary from the session variable. Check if there is an existing value for the current username. If not create a random number and save it in the session. Else just use the saved value.

```
@app.route('/check', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def check():

   # retrieve current username and numbers from your session
   username = session['username']
   numbers = session.get('numbers', {})

   # if no number is existing create a new one and save it to session
   if username not in numbers:
       number = randint(0,4)
       numbers['username'] = number
       session['numbers'] = numbers
   else:
       number = numbers['username']

   return render_template('file.html', number=number, user=username)
```

Comment: Am also using this functionality for the first time and learning about it. Why here `numbers = session.get('numbers', {})` if no session, assign an empty dictionary rather than `None` for example. If there _is_ a session it returns a string, so not sure there is any logic to it returning an empty dictionary if there is not one..

Answer (score -1):

The reason that the session variable is the same for the two users is likely because you're using the same computer / browsing account. It's just like how Facebook remembers your login status after you open a new Facebook tab.

I advise you to get another computer or use a different Chrome Account (top right of Google Chrome) to test out for different users.