# How to access array, list or dictionary from a different function

Tags: python, flask

Basically I am creating a web application through flask where I want to upload an excel file take all the data in the excel file and store it in array, or dictionary for data processing in a different function. I am able to read the excel file and store it in an array, but I was wondering if there's a way to access that data from a different function for processing. If that's possible a pseudo code would help. Thanks !

I've saw other questions on stack overflow but there isn't an exact answer that's helping me

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import xlrd, xlwt


app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

seller_info = []

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.files:
            excel_file = request.files['excel_file']

            wb = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)
            excel_data = pd.read_excel(wb, "Summary", header=None, nrows=5)

            global seller_info
            for row in excel_data.iterrows():
                seller_info.append(row[1][1])



        return render_template('main.html', seller_info=seller_info)



    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process():

    return '??'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to be able to pull the data from "seller_info" list  and use it later in the "process" method.. I'm not really sure how to do this

Comment: Since these are separate requests, you need to save the data in a session variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664055/flask-session-variables

Comment: isn't that for user logins? I just want to access a list or dictionary from a different method

Comment: Oh, I didn't see they were the same route.

Comment: Put the data you want to share in a global variable.

Comment: could you provide an example ?

Comment: I just noticed that you already have `global seller_info`. So you should be able to access it in `process()`.

Comment: Where do you call `process()`? I don't know Flask, is it something it does automatically?

Comment: process() is just another method so when i go to the /process route it should take all the data from seller_info of the main() method

Comment: Another method of what? Like I said, I don't know how Flask works. What causes each of these methods to be called during the same client request?

Comment: when I run it on the development server http://127.0.0.1:5000/  would run the main() method and http://127.0.0.1:5000/process (route /process) would run the process() method

Comment: If you're using a different URL, that's a separate HTTP request. We're back to my original suggestion that you need to use a session variable to keep data between requests.